# How to use different middlewares for different paths in GO?

Tags: go, middleware

Hi I am using [justinas/alice](https://github.com/justinas/alice), and I want to create different middlewares based on paths. i.e if I have path1 and path2, I want to apply m1,m2,m3 for path 1 and m1,m2 for path 2

I tried:

- Creating two mux routers first:

`router := mux.NewRouter()
router2 := mux.NewRouter()`

- Assign the paths to them:

`router.HandleFunc(path1,Func1)
 router2.HandleFunc(path2,Func2)`

- Then I wanted to have something like this

`middlewares:=alice.New(m1,m2).Then(router2)
 middlewaress:=middlewares.Append(middlewares)`

 - Then:

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%d", sconf.Server.Port), middlewaress); err != nil {

    }
```

how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let set the handlers for `router` and `router` to the returned chain from `alice`.

```
// define routers
router := mux.NewRouter() // assuming this is gorilla mux
router2 := mux.NewRouter()

// create alice chains
chain1 := alice.New(m1, m2, m3).Then(func1)
chain2 := alice.New(m1, m2).Then(func2)

// set chains as path handlers
router.HandleFunc(path1, chain1)
router2.HandleFunc(path2, chain2)
```

Comment: doing this leads to an error: cannot use func1 (type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) as type http.Handler in argument to alice.New(m1, m2, m3).Then

Comment: @user6638204 you have to wrap your function in an `http.HandlerFunc` ala `.Then(http.HandlerFunc(func1))`